# Can't apply any Magento patches

Tags: magento, patch

I have the patch file in the root folder of my Magento install. I've used both the `bash` and `sh` commands to run the patch. Everything results in:

```
$ sh stupidpatch1.sh
stupidpatch1.sh: line 32: which: command not found
stupidpatch1.sh: line 33: which: command not found
stupidpatch1.sh: line 34: which: command not found
stupidpatch1.sh: line 35: which: command not found
stupidpatch1.sh: line 36: which: command not found
stupidpatch1.sh: line 38: stupidpatch1.sh: command not found
ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work.
```

The code on those lines in the patch files is:

```
31 # 2. Determine bin path for system tools
32 CAT_BIN=`which cat`
33 PATCH_BIN=`which patch`
34 SED_BIN=`which sed`
35 PWD_BIN=`which pwd`
36 BASENAME_BIN=`which basename`
37
38 BASE_NAME=`$BASENAME_BIN "$0"`
```

Comment: You are missing the `which` util. You’ll have to figure out how to get it installed on your current platform.

Comment: What is your base OS you are trying to run this on? And if Linux, what distribution? The `which` command is used to determine where the commands `cat`, `patch`, `sed` and `pwd` are located. It is missing and that indicates a vastly trimmed down *nix installation or a Windows environment.

Comment: If you're using Windows then this might help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/applying-php-5-4-support-patch-for-magento-ce-1-7-in-a-windows-environment